# Problem with a Division's margin in React

Tags: reactjs, frontend, margin

I have a react component which holds a division called filter. It has a width of 15vw and placed to the left side of the page. I have an another component called product which i want to place to the right of the filter, the problem is the filter division is somehow having a margin that is consuming whole right side. I will provide the CSS and JSX of the filter division. Please help me out of this
Filter.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './Filter.css';
import Sort from './Sort';
function Filter()
{
    return(
        <div className='filter'>
        <h2>Filter</h2>
        <ul className='categories'>
        <li>
        <div className='catItems'>
        <input type='checkbox'></input>
        <span>None</span>
        </div>
        <div className='catItems'>
        <input type='checkbox'></input>
        <span>Electroics</span>
        </div>
        <div className='catItems'>
        <input type='checkbox'></input>
        <span>Home Needs</span>
        </div>
        <div className='catItems'>
        <input type='checkbox'></input>
        <span>Clothing</span>
        </div>
        <div className='catItems'>
        <input type='checkbox'></input>
        <span>Toys</span>
        </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <Sort/>

             
        </div>
    );
}
export default Filter;
```

Filter.CSS

```
.filter {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 149, 0);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start; /* Add this line */
  }
  
  .categories {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .catItems {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 5px;
  }
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    width: 20px;
    margin-right:4px;
}
.sort button{
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

[Image of the website when inspected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBJjW.png)
This is the problem. The dark orange filter part is having a margin which is shown as pale orange color and I want to remove it.

I tried adding margin.right:0; to filter.css but it didnt wordk.

Comment: Place both <Filter /> and <Product /> in the component they're required in and set the display of the parent component to flex, the flex-direction to "row" (based on requirement) and set <Filter />'s width to 50vw or whatever you need it to be.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it worked. Can you please explain why the filter was having that vast margin in the previous case.

Comment: I have added an answer below. You can check that out.

Answer (score 1):

The following should solve your problem:

```
<div> 
 <Filter />
 <Product />
</div>
```

In the markup above, the div is meant to be that of the parent component and must be set to `100vw`. Subsequently, set the `display` of the parent component’s div to `flex`, the `flex-direction` to `row` (based on requirement) and set `<Filter />`'s `width` to `50vw` or whatever you need it to

*This works because divs by default are block elements which occupy entire width of the viewport irrespective of the width you assign them, unless, you build a layout or structure that facilitates otherwise.*

Note: I have used a `div` as an example, you can replace it with whatever block/inline-block element you may have in your parent component (it could be a section/span/article/etc.)

Hope this helps and good luck.